# Is a Kotlin Companion Object just a way to add functions from an interface?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-companion

I am reading the Kotlin in Action book and trying to understand Companion Objects better, are there any other uses for Companion Ojbects other than adding method implementations from an interface/abstract class?

I came across a way of instantiating an object which only works if the class is abstract:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    Fruit.showColor()
}

class Fruit(val name: String) {
    companion object : Apple()
}

abstract class Apple {
    fun showColor(){
        print("I am an apple")
    };
}
```

Comment: No, your example works just fine if the class isn't abstract. It needs to be open (and abstract classes are automatically open), but that has nothing to do with companion objects.

Comment: Good point, yes making the class open works also, but why not regular closed classes? :)

Comment: Because you are extending it. That's what open class means: that you can extend it.

Comment: I understand what open class means and that we can add multiple interfaces inside a companion object, but still didn't find out the wider purpose of this capability...

Answer (score 2):

My mental model for companion object is language level support for safe singletons.  i.e. instead of static methods on a class for Factory or Util methods, you can provide those related methods on the Singleton companion object.

The Companion status gives you a lot of default scoping wins that are similar to the java class with static methods.

Your example seems invalid, because why is the Fruit "singleton" an Apple?

Comment: Yes, but here we can implement multiple interfaces as a companion object, there must be some reason for that other than making a signleton

Comment: No, there's just no reason to remove this capability which non-companion `object`s already have.